# Multilingual NodeJs API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multilingual

i'm developing a REST API in nodejs with swagger and mongoDB.

I am looking for a module or a good practice to help me with multi-language support.
Every objects from collections should have their own translation and i am not sure about the best way to do this.

I had a look to several modules but everything i found is for static data.

The translation is up to the user and can be posted at anytime, in any languages. I need to make sure the user can retrieves his data in every language he posted.

here an example of what i was thinking to do, but i'm not sure this is a recommended practice.

Collection : apartments

Data in english:

```
var apartment = {
        "id": "1x213"
        "name": "Flat 1",
        "price": 100000,
        "rooms": 2,
        "city": "paris",
        "country": "france",
        "zipcode": 75016,
        "address": "11 avenue du general de Gaulles",
        "description": "A wonderful apartment at 2 minutes from the eiffel tower"
        }
```

Data in french:

```
var apartment = {
        "id": "1x214"
        "name": "Appartement 1",
        "price": 100000,
        "rooms": 2,
        "city": "paris",
        "country": "france",
        "zipcode": 75016,
        "address": "11 avenue du general de Gaulles",
        "description": "Un magnifique appartement, à 2 minutes de la tour eiffel"
        }
```

Collection : multilanguage

```
var multilanguage = {
        "id": "1y679"
        "language": [{'en': '1x213' },
                  { 'fr': '1x214'}]
        }
```

I read about some other practice [here](http://www.drzon.net/approaches-to-json-internationalisation-i18n/)  but i'm not sure it's alright for big purpose. It seems a bit messy to me.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally chose the following method.
I think it's the easiest and  more scalable way to do it.
I drew inspiration from ruby on rails good practice.

data in english :

```
var apartment = {
    "id": "1x213",
    "group_id": "c3por2d2",
    "language": "en",
    "name": "Flat 1",
    "price": 100000,
    "rooms": 2,
    "city": "paris",
    "country": "france",
    "zipcode": 75016,
    "address": "11 avenue du general de Gaulles",
    "description": "A wonderful apartment at 2 minutes from the eiffel tower"
    }
```

data in french :

```
var apartment = {
    "id": "1x214",
    "group_id": "c3por2d2",
    "language": "fr",
    "name": "apartment 1",
    "price": 100000,
    "rooms": 2,
    "city": "paris",
    "country": "france",
    "zipcode": 75016,
    "address": "11 avenue du general de Gaulles",
    "description": "Un magnifique appartement, à 2 minutes de la tour eiffel"
    }
```

I've got now a common group_id that i can query to get the data in every language the user posted, i also can query data in a specific language.

Comment: how did this work out for you in the long run? did you find out any other better method than your above solution?

Answer (score 0):

In a document store like mongoDB, I usually make language-dependent information an array of objects like this:

```
var apartment = {
    "id": "1x214",
    "group_id": "c3por2d2",
    "price": 100000,
    "rooms": 2,
    "city": "Paris",
    "country": "France",
    "zipcode": 75016,
    "address": "11 Avenue du Général de Gaulle",
    "names": [{
        "language": "fr_FR",
        "text": "Appartement 1"
    }, {
        "language": "en_US",
        "text": "Apartment 1"
    }, {
        "language": "en_GB",
        "text": "Flat 1"
    }],
    "descriptions": [{
        "language": "fr_FR",
        "text": "Un magnifique appartement, à 2 minutes de la tour eiffel"
    }, {
        "language": "en_US",
        "text": "A wonderful apartment at 2 minutes from the eiffel tower"
    }, {
        "language": "en_GB",
        "text": "A wonderful flat at 2 minutes from the eiffel tower"
    }]
}
```

or into an key-value object like this:

```
var apartment = {
    "id": "1x214",
    "group_id": "c3por2d2",
    "price": 100000,
    "rooms": 2,
    "city": "Paris",
    "country": "France",
    "zipcode": 75016,
    "address": "11 Avenue du Général de Gaulle",
    "names": {
        "fr_FR": "Appartement 1",
        "en_US": "Apartment 1",
        "en_GB": "Flat 1"
    },
    "descriptions": {
        "fr_FR": "Un magnifique appartement, à 2 minutes de la tour eiffel",
        "en_US": "A wonderful apartment at 2 minutes from the eiffel tower",
        "en_GB": "A wonderful flat at 2 minutes from the eiffel tower"
    }
}
```

They're both flexible solutions. They also allow the front-end to switch between languages without reloading the objects. 
You don't need to repeat the non-translatables in multiple objects. An array tends to work better together with statically-typed languages.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's been a while, but you might want to check this out: http://dnd1.com/blog/2016/08/19/multilanguage-api-mongo/

It sets a framework for managing multiple languages in your API. Maybe the "response hook" section would help you.

Comment: Link throwing 404